# distinctUntilChanged creating change in the results

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, rxjs

- I have a search engine code in angular2.
- when I select the search results I need to display the values in the text box with a cross button next to it.
- right now I am getting the results.
- but when I type `h` alone for the first time I am getting some results when I type `m` for the second time I see some results, but when I type `h` for the third time I don't see any results.
- is it due to the `distinctUntilChanged` method or can you tell me how to fix the bug?
- providing my code and stack blitz below
- can you please help me.
- so that in future I can implement myself.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-jbnrru?file=app%2Fsearch-service.ts

```or-tag-here
search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {
    return this.http
        .get(this.baseUrl + this.queryUrl + term)
        .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Comment: When i test it, the http request for libraries?search=hmh is being executed, it just that it returns `{"results":[],"total":0}`

Comment: @NicholasTower what I tried to say is when I type h first time and delete it and type m second time and delete it and third time h in the text box.....why its taking all the three at same time when we type individually is there anyway we can change it according to stackoverflow edit tag functionality...can you explain so that in future I can fix it myself

Comment: oh, if you're deleting characters then the problem is that you havn't implemented the code for deleting characters. updateKeyUp only ever adds to the string (`this.keyapend += event.key`), never shrinks it. Rather than trying to build the string yourself with string concatenation, I'd recommend using `event.target.value` to get the current text of the text input.

Comment: @NicholasTower hey I updated the code for updateKeyUp method but now its showing all the results...can you update in stackblitz its so confusing https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-ectkg3?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Your code is working for me. I type in the input, and i see network requests being made, and the page being updated.

Comment: oh, you have a contentEditable div and are listning to that to? event.target.value will be undefined for the div. It will only work for an input.

Comment: @NicholasTower but right now if I type h it showing different results why https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-ectkg3?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: are you typing in the input or the div?

Comment: @NicholasTower I am typing in the input tag

Answer (score 1):

The rxjs code is pretty good, the use of `debounceTime` and `switchMap` are the same as I would use.

### app.component

The basic problem is you are responding to individual keys, when it would be better (and less code) to respond to the `input` event.

You may also find it works better with non-keyboard user actions like `selectAll + cut` and touch events.

**template**

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="nameModel" 
  (input)="onInput($event)" 
  placeholder="Enter Tag Name">
```

**handler**

```js
onInput(event) {
  const searchTerm = event.target.value;
  console.log('value', searchTerm);
  this.results$ = this.searchService.search(searchTerm)
}
```

In the handler method I also changed result handling to an observable property so that you don't have to subscribe, since subscriptions need to be unsubscribed in `ngOnDestroy` to avoid memory leaks.

**component**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  //results: Object;
  results$: Observable<string[]>
```

**template**

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let result of ((results$ | async) | slice:0:9)"
```

---

### search-service.ts

The service can use some adjustments also.

If you pass in the non-observable search string and then wrap it in `Observable.of()` before debouncing, you can remove the `Subject` code from the component.

Components should be as dumb as possible, to make testing easier and make them easier to modify for new features.

I also destructured the results object and just return the array. The reason for this was that an empty search term was triggering a search, when we already know the result for an empty search term should be an empty array.

```js
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  baseUrl: string = 'https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries';
  queryUrl: string = '?search=';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  search(term: string) {
    return Observable.of(term)
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {
    return term
      ? this.http
          .get(this.baseUrl + this.queryUrl + term)
          .map(res => res.json().results)
      : Observable.of([]);
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-cgkusy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)